# error: cannot find symbol. Running java class with packages through cmd

Tags: java, package

I have a java application `Test`. Inside this I have two java files. `A.java`:

```
import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;

public class A
{
    GenericServlet inter;
}
```

To compile this I used:

```
javac -cp servlet-api.jar A.java
```

It compiled successfully.
Now another java file is `B.java`:

```
import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;

public class B
{
    GenericServlet inter;
    A a = new A();
}
```

When I try to use:

```
javac -cp servlet-api.jar B.java
```

I get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol.
A a = new A();
^
Symbol: class A
location: class B
```

P.S: Please ignore the name of classes & jar files involved as it is for demo purpose only.

Comment: Use a proper IDE and/or a build tool like gradle. Not having to type the build command manually every time will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
javac -cp x.jar;. B.java
```

To include the current directory in the classpath, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you usually get cannot find symbol error when you don't have that class in the classpath. you can fix this issue by adding the path of A.class in the classpath

example javac -cp servlet-api.jar; B.java

Answer (score 0):

Use command:
**javac -cp x.jar A.java B.java**
 include the current directory in the classpath, then it should work.